# What is the most efficient query to get Latest rows with Group By clause on Joined tables in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

**Current Design**

```
Table: 1_notes
------------------------------------------
| id  | text           | created_at          |
------------------------------------------
| 1_1 | u1 first note  | 2018-01-01 10:00:00 |
| 1_2 | u1 second note | 2018-01-03 10:00:00 |


Table: 1_note_timeline
---------------------------------------------------------------------
| note_id  | note_created_at     | likes_count | created_at          |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1_1      | 2018-01-01 10:00:00 | 10          | 2018-01-01 10:00:00 |
| 1_1      | 2018-01-01 10:00:00 | 20          | 2018-01-02 10:00:00 |
| 1_2      | 2018-01-03 10:00:00 | 10          | 2018-01-03 10:00:00 |
| 1_1      | 2018-01-01 10:00:00 | 15          | 2018-01-03 10:00:00 |


Table: 2_notes
--------------------------------------------
| id  | text           | created_at            |
--------------------------------------------
| 2_1 | u2 first note  | 2018-01-01 10:00:00 |
| 2_2 | u2 second note | 2018-01-03 10:00:00 |


Table: 2_note_timeline
---------------------------------------------------------------------
| note_id | note_created_at     | likes_count | created_at          |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2_1     | 2018-01-01 10:00:00 | 10          | 2018-01-01 10:00:00 |
| 2_1     | 2018-01-01 10:00:00 | 20          | 2018-01-02 10:00:00 |
| 2_2     | 2018-01-03 10:00:00 | 10          | 2018-01-03 10:00:00 |
| 2_1     | 2018-01-01 10:00:00 | 15          | 2018-01-03 10:00:00 |
```

ForEach user there are 2 tables for their notes data.

- {{userId}}_notes table contain the notes of user with id `userId`
- {{userId}}_note_timeline table tracks notes likes_count data every day

**Required result should have:**

- First 2 notes across both users that have most likes
- Likes count must be latest (and NOT MAX_VALUE because notes likes_count can decrease with time)

**Final Output**

```
Output
---------------------------------------------------------------
| note_id | note_created_at     | likes_count | text          |
---------------------------------------------------------------
| 1_1     | 2018-01-01 10:00:00 | 15          | u1 first note |
| 2_1     | 2018-01-01 10:00:00 | 15          | u2 first note |
```

Comment: Storing different users data in different tables is definitely not the best way to structure the data.  You should have one set of tables for *all* users.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Doing that would increase cost tremendously. As each user have millions of notes and millions of note_timeline. And at a time I only need to query atmost 4 users at a time.

Comment: @GordonLinoff BigQuery allow to partition by Ingestion-time or TIMESTAMP/DATE column (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables). So, as per your suggestion I won't be able to partition it by userID.
And benefit of my current design is that I will be able to partition each user notes by month.

Comment: @GordonLinoff why have you deleted your comment? Please don't do that, future users will have trouble understanding the context.
Along with that BigQuery provides a way to automate the building of these same schema tables (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#template-tables)

Comment: @user2579651 . . . I thought BigQuery had implemented that functionality.  My comment is just misleading until improved partitioning is released.

Comment: @user2576951 - Please clarify - `First 2 notes across both users that have most likes` - does it mean that both output rows can be for the same user? or it should be one for each

Comment: Instead of waiting for "improved partitioning", maybe we could still have just 1 table with "clustering" functionality with user_id being the the cluster column ?

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant output rows can be either from same user/different user based on LikesCount. The rows are purely chosen on LikesCount.

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant Simply saying we want to know: right now which 2 notes are trending.

Comment: @Sourygna It's still in Beta and I'm afraid to use that in production.

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant could you please help me with another question [ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54627429 ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.user_notes` AS (
  SELECT * FROM `project.dataset.user1_notes` UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM `project.dataset.user2_notes`
), `project.dataset.user_note_timeline` AS (
  SELECT * FROM `project.dataset.user1_note_timeline` UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM `project.dataset.user2_note_timeline`
)
SELECT note_id, note_created_at, likes_count, text 
FROM (
  SELECT note_id, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(note_created_at, likes_count, created_at) ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)].*
  FROM `project.dataset.user_note_timeline`
  GROUP BY note_id
  ORDER BY likes_count DESC, note_created_at
  LIMIT 2
) t
JOIN `project.dataset.user_notes` n
ON note_id  = id
```

Comment: Thanks, Sir, It worked perfectly. Could you please guide me, flaws in current design. I'm really afraid should I go with this design? Right now I can see that with this design I won't be able to get trending notes from all the users (BigQuery restrict MAX 1000 tables in single query, so atmost I will be able to query upto 500_user_notes at a time, then have to programatically call another query and finally have to join the result BUT then how could I achieve pagination)

Comment: this is quite different question - I will think of it. obviously having two tables per each user is a terrible idea. why you went this direction? explain your way of thinking - this might help in producing good recommendation for you

Comment: Although, you mentioned that `at a time I only need to query at most 4 users at a time` - so why you worry of MAX 1000? you will need just 8 - so explain yourself better

Comment: That's correct right now I need to query at most 4 users. But I am trying to foresee if in future I have to query all the users than can I go with this design. I have split tables for each user to reduce the Query Cost. That's the ONLY reason. I'm with you that it's a terrible idea but I am afraid saving Query Cost now could cost much more in future (redesign/moving data)

Comment: And Sir, the best cheapest way I can think of to query all the user notes in future is by having a seprate tables for each user along with that creating a new table containing allUsers_note_timeline (each noteId is prefixed by userId so no worry about noteId duplication and partitioning that table by TIMESTAMP). So if I have to query upto 500 users I can use seprate tables and If I have to query > 500 users than use the allUsers_note_timeline table. Sir, Please suggest if there is any other better and cheap way.

Answer (score 0):

### Hope this will solve your issue

```
SELECT TOP 1 t1.note_id, t1.note_created_at, t1.likes_count, t2.[text]
  FROM 1_note_timeline t1 INNER JOIN 1_notes t2 ON t1.note_id = t2.Id
 ORDER BY t1.created_at DESC

UNION

SELECT TOP 1 t1.note_id, t1.note_created_at, t1.likes_count, t2.[text]
  FROM 2_note_timeline t1 INNER JOIN 2_notes t2 ON t1.note_id = t2.Id
 ORDER BY t1.created_at DESC
```

It is better to introduce indices for the tables in order to improve performance.