# Most efficient query to extract hashtags timeline grouped by date in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to extract the Hashtag Timeline grouped by date from the notes data column. Data is a JSON column. We have to count hashtags that can be in 't' OR 'd' property

```
Table: notes
----------------------------------------------------------------------
| id | data                                    | created_at          |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | {"t":"#hash1 title","d":"#hash1 desc"}  | 2018-01-01 10:00:00 |
| 2  | {"t":"#hash1 title","d":"#hash1 desc"}  | 2018-01-01 11:00:00 |
| 3  | {"t":"title","d":"#hash1 #hash2 desc"}  | 2018-01-03 10:00:00 |
```

As described below the required output needs to have each hashtag with it's corresponding timeline in format: `DATE:COUNT|DATE:COUNT|DATE:COUNT`

```
Required Output
----------------------------------------------------------
| hashtag                    | timeline                  |
----------------------------------------------------------
| #hash1                     | 2018-01-01:4|2018-01-03:1 |
| #hash2                     | 2018-01-03:1              |
```

What is the most efficient single query that has all these features:

- Extract Hashtags from 't' AND 'd' property of data.
- Count the Hashtags grouped by date.
- Concatenate respective hashtag timeline in the desired format.

**UPDATE 1:**
Below is my query. It's inefficient because I have to UNNEST 2 times. I am not able to figure out how to make it efficient.

```
WITH
r0 AS (
  SELECT JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(data, '$[d]') as data, created_at
  FROM `notes`
  UNION ALL
  SELECT JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(data, '$[t]') as data, created_at
  from `notes`      
),
r1 AS (
  SELECT created_at, REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(data, r"#(\w*[0-9a-zA-Z]+\w*[0-9a-zA-Z])") AS hashtags
  FROM r0
),
r2 AS (
  SELECT ARRAY_AGG(DATE(created_at)) as created_at_dates, hashtag
  FROM r1, UNNEST(hashtags) hashtag
  GROUP BY hashtag
),
r3 AS (
  SELECT created_at_date, hashtag
  FROM r2, UNNEST(created_at_dates) created_at_date
),
r4 AS (
  SELECT hashtag, created_at_date, count(created_at_date) as day_val
  FROM r3
  GROUP BY hashtag, created_at_date
  ORDER BY created_at_date
)
SELECT hashtag, STRING_AGG(CONCAT(CAST(created_at_date as STRING),':',CAST(day_val as STRING)), '|') as timeline
FROM r4
GROUP BY hashtag
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT hashtag,
  STRING_AGG(CONCAT(day, ':', cnt), '|' ORDER BY day) AS timeline
FROM (
  SELECT hashtag,
    CAST(DATE(created_at) AS STRING) day,
    CAST(COUNT(1) AS STRING) cnt
  FROM `project.dataset.table`,
  UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(data, r'"(?:t|d)":(".*?")')) val,
  UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(val, r'(#.*?)\s')) hashtag
  GROUP BY hashtag, day
)
GROUP BY hashtag
```

If you need to extract for more than just `t` and `d` properties - you just add them into `(?:t|d)` list as opposed to using multiple `UNION ALL`'s

if to execute above on sample data in your question  - result is

```
Row hashtag timeline     
1   #hash1  2018-01-01:4|2018-01-03:1    
2   #hash2  2018-01-03:1
```

> Update to address "deep structure" mentioned in @user2576951 comment

See below update along with dummy data to test with

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, '{"x":"title","t":"#hash1 title","d":"help #hash1 desc"}' data, TIMESTAMP '2018-01-01 10:00:00' created_at UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, '{"t":"#hash1 title","y":"title","d":"#hash1 desc"}', '2018-01-01 11:00:00' UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, '{"t":"title","d":"#hash1 #hash2 desc","z":"title"}', '2018-01-03 10:00:00' UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, '{"t":"title","d":"description","snippet":{"t":"#hash1","st":"#hash1", "ssd":"#hash3"}}', '2018-02-03 10:00:00'
)
SELECT hashtag,
  STRING_AGG(CONCAT(day, ':', cnt), '|' ORDER BY day) AS timeline
FROM (
  SELECT 
    hashtag, 
    CAST(DATE(created_at) AS STRING) day,
    CAST(COUNT(1) AS STRING) cnt
  FROM `project.dataset.table`,
  UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(data, r'"(?:t|d|st|sd)":"(.*?)"')) val,
  UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(val, r'(#.*?)(?:$|\s)')) hashtag
  GROUP BY hashtag, day
)
GROUP BY hashtag
-- ORDER BY hashtag
```

with output

```
Row hashtag timeline     
1   #hash1  2018-01-01:4|2018-01-03:1|2018-02-03:2   
2   #hash2  2018-01-03:1
```

as you can see here hashtags are collected from nested elements and "ssd" was not matched even though `sd` is part of it

I think above addresses your both comments / concerns

Comment: Thanks! your query results in the desired output. ONLY remaining issue is some notes have deep structure eg. `{"t":"title","d":"description","snippet":{"st":"snippetTitle","sd":"snippetDesc"}}`. here snippetTitle & snippet Desc can also have hashtag that needs to be counted for. How to tackle this situation?

Comment: `"(?:t|d|st|sd)":(".*?")` will work... but it will accidently matches some other property.... eg.. `st` property could be in `notSnippet` property that i don't want to include eg... `{"t":"title","d":"description","snippet":{"st":"snippetTitle","sd":"snippetDesc"},"notSnippet":{"st":"snippetTitle","sd":"snippetDesc"}}`

Comment: Sir, please add this in your dataset & run::: `SELECT 5, '{"snippet":{"st":"#include","sd":"#include"},"notSnippet":{"st":"#donotInclude","sd":"#donotInclude"}}', '2018-02-03 10:00:00'`. My concern is that #donotInclude will be counted but I don't want to include that in final output as i want only `snippet.st` & `snippet.sd` hashtags AND NOT `notSnippet.st` & `notSnippet.sd` hashtags

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is "most efficient", but this should do what you want:

```
select hashtag,
       array_agg(concat(created_at, ':', cast(cnt as string))
from (select hashtag, created_at, count(*) as cnt
      from ((select json_extract_scalar(data, '$[d]') as hashtag, created_at
             from t
            ) union all
            (select json_extract_scalar(data, '$[t]') as hashtag, created_at
             from t
            ) 
           ) h
      group by hash
     ) ch
group by hashtag;
```

Comment: I have updated my question with my inefficient query. Please help me to make it efficient... ('m afraid but your query does not result in expected output)